# Parsing Error PHP, Unexpected EOF

Tags: php, parsing, syntax-error, eof

I have this seemingly simple piece of PHP that isn't parsing correctly.  Its a php landing page where people need to input a password they were given and the site goes and grabs the index file outside of the root.  I've had it working fine for years but I am guessing there is a new syntax that I am unfamiliar with that is causing this to fail?

```
<?php
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
 if($pass == "APASSWORDISHERE")
{
    include("../home.html");
}
else
{
if(isset($_POST))
{?>

        <form method="POST" action="home.php">
        Password <input type="password" name="pass"></input><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go"></input>
        </form>
<?}
}
?>
```

Comment: Well `}}` all by itself is not valid PHP code.

Comment: why did you mark this as a duplicate

Comment: Use `<?php` instead of `<?` and make sure you have a space between `<?php` and following code.